# PJSIP on iOS, compiler error of "undeclared type `pj_thread_t`"

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, pjsip

I had built PJSIP 2.7.1 and was integrating it for an iOS app written in Swift. Everything worked so I believed it was built the right way, all libs and headers were in the right place too, until one day I was trying to call lib functions from an external thread so I had to register this thread by using `pj_thread_register()` and declared a `pj_thread_t` type variable, the compiler started to complain about that the type `pj_thread_t` was undeclared.

I found the `pj_thread_t` was declared in `pj/types.h` and was defined in `pj/os_core_linux_kernel.c`. The `types.h` was already included in the header search path and I supposed it should work. I guess I must have missed something here.

Comment: `#import <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>` is the only thing I have in my Bridging-Header file for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem in my Swift project. My solution is create a kind of wrapper file in ObjC. Swift and ObjC works with memory in different ways. This is why my wrapper works good. Now I can call `pj_thread_t` inside my wrapper file.

```
pjsip (C) --> MyWrapper file (ObjC) --> myProject' files (Swift)
```

MyProject-Bridging-Header.h file contain only one row:

```
#import "MyWrapper.h"
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, this sounds making sense to me. For now I'm putting the pjsip lib function calls inside swift main thread to get around. I would try your way to solve it.